Fail to use ox-taskjuggler of org-contrib to export tjp file
I want to use taskjuggler to manage project, and I am a Emacs user. So I want to export org file as tjp file, it will be quick to start using it, as I thought.
I install taskjuggler successfully, then I want to try it within Emacs. But when I execute elisp function org-taskjuggler-export, there always has message "Symbol’s function definition is void: nil". I can’t figure out what’s wrong result in this. Org-mode seems always work fine for me.
I think it's problem of export function, not any others. But if I still want to use emacs, there may not has any other ways to export as tjp, except I write tjp file.
Please help me to take a look at it. I would really appreciate it.

This issue seems to be caused by the latest version of org-contrib (0.6). Apparently support for ox-taskjuggler is being dropped.
Reverting to version 0.4.2 (https://elpa.nongnu.org/nongnu/org-contrib-0.4.2.tar.lz) fixed it for me.

You (or the OP) can volunteer to be the ox-taskjuggler maintainer. That will keep it in Org contrib. You will need to learn a bit about the code and be able to do simple fixes if bug reports come in, but the Org mode mailing list is an invaluable resource (and in general, it probably helps more to know the taskjuggler side, than to know the Org mode side). You can even try it for a while and if it does not work out for you, you can always resign the maintainership: no harm done.
